# How do I fix this code about index string?

Tags: python

I make a function to input string and return with head and tail with two indexes without space and punctuation. but it's return only "empty string"

```
def hello(word):
    str_cnt = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in string.whitespace and letter not in string.punctuation:
            str_cnt += letter    
            if len(str_cnt) < 2 :
                return "empty string"
            else:
                return str_cnt[:2] + str_cnt[-2:]

word = input("Input String : ")
result = hello(word)
print("Result: ",result)
```

I expect when I input "hello world!", and the actual output is "held"

or "Hi!" = "HiHi".

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss-indented the last `if` block:

```
import string
def hello(word):
    str_cnt = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in string.whitespace and letter not in string.punctuation:
            str_cnt += letter    
    if len(str_cnt) < 2 :
        return "empty string"
    else:
        return str_cnt[:2] + str_cnt[-2:]

word = input("Input String : ")
result = hello(word)
print("Result: ",result)
```

Example output:

```
Input String : Hello World!
Result:  Held
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply incorrect indentation:

```
import string

def hello(word):
    str_cnt = ""

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in string.whitespace and letter not in string.punctuation:
            str_cnt += letter

    if len(str_cnt) < 2:
        return "empty string"

    return str_cnt[:2] + str_cnt[-2:]

word = input("Input String: ")
result = hello(word)
print("Result: ", result)
```

Indentation is everything in Python!

```
> python3 test.py
Input String: hello world!
Result:  held
>
```

However, if the input is long, this is the wrong way to go about the problem.  We test a lot of characters we'll never use against the `whitespace` and `punctuation` lists.  Instead we should grab the first two valid characters from either end of the list and ignore the middle.  Something like:

```
def hello(word):
    unwanted = string.whitespace + string.punctuation
    str_start = ""

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in unwanted:
            str_start += letter

            if len(str_start) == 2:
                break

    if len(str_start) < 2:
        return "empty string"

    str_end = ""

    for idx in range(len(word) - 1, -1, -1):
        if word[idx] not in unwanted:
            str_end = word[idx] + str_end

            if len(str_end) == 2:
                break

    return str_start + str_end
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> python3 test2.py
Input String: telecommunications!
Result: tens
>
```

The letters `'lecommunicatio'` were never tested as they had no effect on the eventual outcome.

Comment: @thexsecret, I've added a second example that tries to avoid unnecessary tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you `return` after the first iteration through the work, no matter what.

Move the `return` nogic *after* the logic:

```
def hello(word):
    str_cnt = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in string.whitespace and letter not in string.punctuation:
            str_cnt += letter    
    if len(str_cnt) < 2 :
        return "empty string"
    else:
        return str_cnt[:2] + str_cnt[-2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indentation as everyone says, after correcting which it works. I would do it more pythonically as:

```
def hello(word):
    w = ''.join([x for x in word if x not in string.whitespace and x not in string.punctuation])
    return w[:2] + w[-2:] if len(w) > 1 else 'empty string'
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> hello('hello world!')
held
```